# this returns window object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

in my example i want to simulate jquery.each method as I created `JQueryX` object that can select with class selector `JQueryX(.classname)` and adds it to its property `selection` which is an array now i'm stuck with the line `console.log(this, 'i was clicked');` where `this` returns the window object

```
var x = new JQueryX('.drg');

x.each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(this, 'i was clicked');
    });
});

JQueryX.prototype.each = function (func,paras){
    paras = paras || [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.selection.length; i++) {
        var that = this.selection[i];
        console.log(that);
        func.apply(that,paras);
    }
};
```

and the strange thing for me is `this` returns the object I want if i called it from the line `console.log(this);`

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent jQuery?

Comment: In what way are you stuck? What is your question?

Comment: Is `this.selection` an array of DOM elements?

Comment: Show us the definition of `JQueryX`.

Comment: yes it contains the objects that matched the selection `.drg`

Comment: Then post how you select nodes and assign them to `this.selection`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because the listener function is called by the window, try that :

```
x.each(function() {
    var self = this;
    this.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(self, 'i was clicked')
    });
});
```

In fact when you add a callback function to your object `this.addEventListener(...)` it's not the object himself who call the function when the event append, it's the window. So that's why `this` is the window in you function.

So you have to save the reference of your object with `var self = this;` then when the callback method will be called it will have the correct reference to your object.

Comment: it worked but can you please clarify this for me because I can't get it

Comment: @Romany-Saad put the question as resolved i edit it to add some more informations :)

Comment: I needed to wait 10 minutes to mark it

Comment: @Romany-Saad Ok no problem :) hope it helped you

Comment: You are wrong. `this` refers to the node the event is attached when using the `addEventListener`. The problem lies with the code that stores the references in the `this.selection`. It stores a reference to the `window` object.

Comment: @Ludovic thank you but i'm new can't vote you up

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Maybe i'm wrong but you are too ! as the OP said to this question : `Is this.selection an array of DOM elements?` he answered: `yes it contains the objects that matched the selection .drg` Please remove your downvote if you don't have any other solution